# Pass values selected item ListView to next activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-sqlite

When clicked on an item in my ListView I would like to open the 2nd activity and display the description and reason in 2 different TextView's. I can't figure out how to pass the data from the selected item into the Intent and how to display the values in the TextView's (second activity). For the record I'm using SQLite (commonsware).

It's probably the best way to send the entire record as an object instead of asking each element (description, reason) of the record?

Thanks in advance!!

**I've created a class "OpenHelper":**

```
public class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String NAME = "oef.db";
public static final int VERSION = 1; 

public OpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    onUpgrade(db, 1, VERSION);  
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sqlCreateTodo = "CREATE TABLE TODOS (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, description TEXT, reason TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sqlCreateTodo);

    String sqlInsertTodo = "INSERT INTO TODOS (description, reason) VALUES(?,?)";
    db.execSQL(sqlInsertTodo, new Object[] { "Buy Christmas presents.", "Family" });
    db.execSQL(sqlInsertTodo, new Object[] { "Buy turkey.", "Family" });
    db.execSQL(sqlInsertTodo, new Object[] { "Buy beer.", "Me" });
    db.execSQL(sqlInsertTodo, new Object[] { "Buy more beer.", "Me" });
    db.execSQL(sqlInsertTodo, new Object[] { "Buy tree.", "Family" });  
}
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private static final int TEST_LOADER = 0;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Detail.class);
    intent.putExtra("test", "test");
    startActivity(intent);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] from = new String[] { "description" };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(TEST_LOADER, null, this); 
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (id == TEST_LOADER){
    SQLiteCursorLoader cursorLoader = new SQLiteCursorLoader(this, new OpenHelper(this), "SELECT _id, description FROM TODOS", null);   
        return cursorLoader;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    adapter.swapCursor(arg1);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

EDIT:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] from = new String[] { "description" };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(TEST_LOADER, null, this); 

    ListView List= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);  
    List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detail.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

EDIT2:

```
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.howest.mad.examen.timtest/be.howest.mad.examen.timtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at be.howest.mad.examen.timtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-14 11:12:24.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: pass the id, then make a query using the id.

Comment: use the extras for bundles of the intent you're calling : 
Intent(context,NewActivity.class).putExtra("action", value);

and then on the onCreate() of your activity just get them:
String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");

Comment: You have "ListView List=", use "ListView list = "

Answer (score 2):

I use the following in my application:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detail.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In the Detail class:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b = getIntent().getExtras();
long id = b.getLong("id");
```

Comment: I've edited the onCreate method resulting in a NullPointerException. How can I use the data from the Bundle in a TextView? 

     TextView t = new TextView(this); 
     t =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDescription);
     t.setText(.....);

Comment: Where's your call to setContentView()?

Comment: @user1951083 There are some major errors in the edited part you added.

Comment: @Nfear You mean: (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()?
Else i'm getting the following error: The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})

Comment: You have "ListView List=", use "ListView list = "

Comment: @Melquiades setContentView() is not necessary in a ListActivity

Comment: @Nfear Is it possible I'm getting the NullPointerException because intent.getExtras() returns null when the intent doesn't have any extras?

Comment: @Nfear Added the logcat, nothing seems to spot out.
Any other major errors that you've noticed. (except the ListView List)

Comment: What is line 48 in MainActivity?

Comment: listtest.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

Comment: @Nfear solved everything but: How to display the values in the textview on the next acitvity?

  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b = getIntent().getExtras();
  long id = b.getLong("id");
        
  TextView t = new TextView(this); 
     t =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDescription);
     t.setText("");

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: use t.setText(String.valueOf(id));

Comment: @Nfear Thanks! But when clicking on the first record "Buy christmas presents". it goes to the next activity and shows "1" (id) in the textbox instead of the text.

Comment: Oh, you need to query the database for that id to get the description. I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for helping, created a new topic!

Answer (score 0):

First, You just do that change

> List to mList

then change code of onItemClick

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detail.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",adapter.getItem(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setting the parameter**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, <Name-of-the-Activity>.class);
intent.putExtra("id",id);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Getting parameters** (Shortcut)

`String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");`